# Did I make a good choice of computer hardware?

Tags: hardware, intel

Today I bought a new notebook. Configuration:

- I3 @ 2,1GHZ
- 4GB ram
- 500GB HD
- Intel HD Graphics 3000

It came with Windows 7; I'm a Ubuntu solid user by 1 year. So, I don't want to use Windows anymore in the machine (1 day in Windows is enough to make my hair go white).

Will Ubuntu run well on this machine? Is this machine good for tasks like Web Browsing with about 20 tabs open, while watching videos on YouTube, and listening to music with Rhythmbox?

Did I make a good choice?

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you mentioned the make/model of the laptop. Despite the basic components which look like they'd work fine, laptop manufacturers use a lot of "proprietary" components (card readers, video cards, the BIOS, and so on) that *may* give trouble with Ubuntu.

A good resource of information on whether it works or not is the Ubuntu certified system list, these systems are actively tested to ensure they work well with Ubuntu:

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification

Also, Ubuntu Friendly is a community-driven project where users test their systems and report back on whether they work or not:

https://friendly.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should not have any problems.

I'm currently running a

- i5 @ 3.0Ghz
- 8GB RAM
- Intel® HD Graphics 2000

I have little bit better CPU than yours and more RAM, I believe that the graphics card are about the same(I think that the HD 3000 is the laptop  model and the HD 2000 is the desktop) but you *may* have a slightly better Graphics card.

While I do have more RAM I almost never use more than 1.5GB, most of the time I'
m only using 800-1000MB so you should have plenty of RAM.

I don't usually have 20 tabs open but I have 10 every so often and don't notice any less performance than when I only have one or two open.

Watching You Tube videos presents no problems for me even if a have more than one tab open while doing so, you should have no problem there either.

Up until this Feb. I was running Ubuntu on my old computer(2.5Ghz dual core Intel) that was about 6 years old and had no problems with that one either.

In short, I would have no worries recommending the laptop you bought even if you had asked before the purchase. I am very happy with my very similar system, enjoy yours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu will run on almost all hardware.